# How to upload pdf to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, jmeter

I recorded jmeter script with blazemeter to upload a pdf file to the s3 bucket.When I parameterize the required values and execute the script to upload the file I am getting the error response

Response code: 403
Response message: Forbidden

All the parameters have correct values passed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should also get an appropriate [Error Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList) which provides way more information regarding what's wrong, i.e. `Access Denied` or `All access to this Amazon S3 resource has been disabled.`, once you know the root cause you should be able to figure out what needs to be done in order to resolve the issue.

Also double check all the request parameters using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), for example you cannot record and replay `X-Amz-Signature`, you need to generate a proper one for each and every request, see [How to Handle Dynamic AWS SigV4 in JMeter for API Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-dynamic-aws-sigv4-in-jmeter-for-api-testing) article for more details